# security management and security engineering difference

Tags: software, operations

Is there a difference between "security management" and "security engineering"? I read about security engineering in some places and security management in others, but  I really can't find what the difference is between those.

Comment: Assuming that you have looked up those terms, perhaps you can add to your question about what specifically you don't understand about the definitions that you've found.

Comment: Some context also wouldn't go amiss, like linking to and/or quoting relevant excerpts from your sources that you mention you have read.

Answer (score 1):

Security Management is more about defining what should be done. For instance you want to have a document classification, compliance, password policy, remote access policy, ... which are preferably technology independant.

Security Engineering is more about implementing all of the defined policies into a technology.